# Subscribe to OnToolBarChanged event PDFTronViewCtrl

Tags: pdftron

Using pdftron Xamarin viewer control for android and not able to listen to ToolbarChanged event.
Pdf files tabs are opened toolbars are shown or hidden based on a condition. I have to save and restore the selected toolbar when tab is changed.

How to do this?

Note: I see ontoolbarchanged but I think event implementation for ToolbarChanged is not available in c#?

[image]

Also when I try to open in AnnotationMode the annotation tools are not shown.

[image]

One more bug is that LastTabClosed event is fired twice.

Am solving the Navigation popped twice using a flag as mentioned below.

```
    bool flagPopped;

    private void MDocumentView_LastTabClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!flagPopped)
            Element.Navigation.PopAsync();
        flagPopped = true;
    }
```

Comment: Is this issue on both iOS and Android? If not, exactly which one are you asking about?

Comment: Android. We haven't started working on this for iOS yet

Comment: @Ryan please check the latest screenshot. AdvancedViewer is quite buggy now when Multitab is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Am able to listen to the pdftronviewctrl events using below code. But the problem is that it doesn't support ToolManager per tab, so it is not possible to achieve using the current version. Also ToolbarChanged event is fired for TabChanged event also, making it useless to listen for Tab level control.

```
public class ToolbarChangedListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnToolbarChangedListener
{
    public event EventHandler<string> ToolbarChanged;
    
    public void OnToolbarChanged(string newToolbar)
    {
        ToolbarChanged?.Invoke(this, newToolbar);
    }
}
    
var toolbarListerner = new ToolbarChangedListener();
mDocumentView.MPdfViewCtrlTabHostFragment.AddOnToolbarChangedListener(toolbarListerner);
toolbarListerner.ToolbarChanged += ToolbarListerner_ToolbarChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code you are not using any instances of ToolManager. Could you describe to us specifically which PDFViewCtrl events you are listening to and any sample code associated with these listeners?

As for ToolbarChanged listener (separate from PDFViewCtrl events), the event is raised after the toolbar has been inflated so it may not be the correct solution for the use case you described. One possible solution is to listen for tab loaded and changed events, then store/load your toolbar state at that point.

Could you contact support https://www.pdftron.com/company/contact-us/ regarding this? From there we can provide you with one-on-one support and help you with a solution for your use case.

Best Regards,
Branden Fung